# PHP totalling column and simplifying Sessions

Tags: php

I'm trying to total a column in a table of prices and it's not working out for me. I've looked at a ton of solutions such as `array_sum()` but it's not displaying anything for me. This is a cart page where I'm `post`ing items to a session and then displaying in a `for` loop. I'm not sure if my `sessions` are overly complicated or what. Here is my `session` and `post` code:

```
session_start();

if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $_SESSION['item'][] = array($_POST['item'], $_POST['price']);
}

?>
```

And here is my `for` loop section of code:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($_SESSION['item']); $i++){
    $prices = $_SESSION['item'][$i][1];
         $sum = 0;
         $sum += $_SESSION['item'][$i][1];
         print $sum;
?>

<tr>
    <td class="left"> <?php print_r($_SESSION['item'][$i][0]) ?></td>
    <td class="center"><?php echo "$ " . $_SESSION['item'][$i][1] ?></td>
</tr> 

<?php
}
?>

<tr>
    <td class="center">Total:</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

</table><br>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Best Practise: `echo "$ ". ` would be better as `echo '$ '.` because in double quotes the `$` is identiied as a PHP variable tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your current forloop with the following:

You were assigning `$sum=0;` inside loop so every time loop executed, your `$sum` variable would be assigned to zero and hence you would lose its value.

*Sidenote:* You should consider printing sum outside of loop.

```
$sum = 0;
for($i=0; $i < count($_SESSION['item']); $i++){
    $prices = $_SESSION['item'][$i][1];
    $sum += $_SESSION['item'][$i][1];
    print $sum;
?>
```

Comment: Also, i guess that sum should be session variable, too, or 0, if session is not set?

Comment: @Bhaumik Mehta, thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, it's just printing each item's cost side by side like this "99.99 159.98".

Comment: @Nick So print it once the loop ends.

Comment: @Bhaumik Mehta, I both love and hate when it's something as simple as that. Definitely makes me feel dumb! Anyways, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Martin, pretty much exactly what Bhaumhik Mehta showed me. I was just dumb and didn't print the $sum outside of the loop to actually make it total up.

Comment: @Nick I have been through that stage :)

Answer (score 0):

At first your code must be like this:

```
$sum = 0;
for($i=0; $i < count($_SESSION['item']); $i++){
         $prices = $_SESSION['item'][$i][1];
         $sum += $prices;

?>

<tr>
    <td class="left"> <?php print_r($_SESSION['item'][$i][0]) ?></td>
    <td class="center"><?php echo "$ " . $_SESSION['item'][$i][1] ?></td>
</tr> 

<?php
}
?>

<tr>
    <td class="center">Total: <?=$sum?></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

</table><br>
```

And the second if you want to sum column of prices from database then you can use mysql SUM function
[Reference for mysql SUM](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_sum.asp)